# VM can get leased an IP address from DHCP server, it can connect to local devices but it can't connect to my routers config page or the internet?

Tags: networking, windows-10, virtualbox, pfsense

I have a windows 10 machine and a separate machine running pfsesense.

On Windows 10 I am using virtual box and I created an Ubuntu 16.04 x64 VM. I put the VM in bridged mode instead of NAT.

When I look at the connection info on the VM, it shows all the right settings. It shows my router `10.12.1.1`, my DHCP server has `10.12.1.130-150` reserved for static entries and it leases non static addresses starting at `10.12.1.11`. I didn't make a static entry for the VM, so the VM indicates it was given an IP of `10.12.1.11`. I use pihole as my DNS server, `10.12.1.190`. The DHCP server hands out that address as the DNS server as well.

So the VM is able to talk to the DHCP server which is running on `10.12.1.1`, it is able to be leased an IP address and a DNS address, I can remotely connect to my other computers on the network(`10.12.1.131` and `10.12.1.190`), I can access the webpage for `10.12.1.190`. I didn't manually enter the IP settings for the VM. They were obtained automatically.

But I can't access the webpage for my router, `10.12.1.1` nor can I ping it nor can I visit internet pages like google. Its not an internet issue because every other device in my house works fine and they're all on the same network.

Makes no sense that it can communicate with devices connected to the router but it can't connect to the router, but it can connect to the router enough to obtain a DHCP lease.

Ran the command.

`default via 10.12.1.1 dev enp0s3 proto static metric 100`

Comment: Has your VM been given a default gateway so it knows where to point requests for addresses it cannot resolve locally? In Terminal type `ip route | grep default` and paste up into your question the result.

Comment: added it @Kinnectus

Comment: What's the error when you try to connect to the router GUI?

Comment: Nothing. It never times out. It just says "connecting to 10.12.1.1" for like 10 minutes and then it stops trying to connect and just shows a blank new tab page just like where it started off.

Comment: What happens if you turn off the Windows (host) firewall?

Comment: Nothing. Still wont work

Comment: I should also mention that I'm running another VM. My pihole dns server, `10.12.1.190` is running on an Ubuntu server VM on my windows desktop. I thought maybe that was the issue since I already have a VM in bridged mode but I just powered on a Windows XP VM and that is able to get on the internet. So everything can get internet, including other VMs, So I then assumed the Ubuntu install was messed up or the ISO was  bad, So instead of using a 16.04 install I deleted it and got a fresh 17.04 install. Both had the proble,

Comment: I wonder... shutdown  your VM and go to it's settings -> Look under the "network" settings for your virtual network adapter -> change the "Promiscuous mode" to "Allow all" and "cable connected" to "ticked". See here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/363003/no-internet-connection-on-virtualbox-windows-7-as-guest-ubuntu-13-04-as-host -> start your VM and see if that makes a difference